# How can add elements to an array but put each element in a separate row in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array question. When I use `.push` to put the elements in the array, they are printed in the console.log one after the other. [https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push]
Is there a way to output each element to an extra row in this array? I have a default where I should log errors. These errors are to be output in an array for control with one line per error message.

```
let sports = ['soccer', 'baseball']
let total = sports.push('football', 'swimming')

console.log(sports)  // ['soccer', 'baseball', 'football', 'swimming']
```

I mean like this?

```
console.log(sports)       

['soccer', // line 1
 'baseball', // line 2
 'football', // line 3
 'swimming'] // line 4
```

Comment: Like `console.table(sports)`? However, the console will have nothing to do with your actual error log. You might want to look into [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join): `console.log(sports.join('\n'))`.

Comment: @Lain But `join` then gives that as a string and returns that, doesn't it? Then I no longer have an array. And table is not what I mean either. I have exactly that default.

Comment: sports.forEach(element => console.log(element)) ? This will output each element in a new line

Comment: Everything you output is a string.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you expect as an output ?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the task either. 

Your function should return an array containing all errors found.
found. Output the array for checking - one line per error message.

And then list the second example of the array. But without console.log.

Answer (score 0):

u can use a loop

```js
    let sports = ['soccer', 'baseball']
    let total = sports.push('football', 'swimming')

    //table
    console.table(sports)  
    // loop
    sports.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element);
    });
```